# Can't Compile C++ Code on NetBeans 7.0

Tags: c++, netbeans, configuration, makefile, mingw

I just installed NetBeans 7.0 with C++ package. It asked for C++ compiler - I installed MinGW. I added it to NetBeans (so it recognize it). I think that it's all correct...

I wrote very simple C++ application in *main.cpp* and tried to compile it...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    std::cout << "Hello, world!";


    return 0;

}
```

It complains about "Make Command" (under Tools -> Options -> C/C++ -> Build Tools). I tried to fix it and type *C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe* in there. I tried to compile it again! Here's the error message...

> ```
> "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
> make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/admin/Documents/C++/helloWorld'
> "/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/helloworld.exe
> make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/admin/Documents/C++/helloWorld'
> make[2]: mkdir: Command not found
> mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
> make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 127
> make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
> make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/admin/Documents/C++/helloWorld'
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/admin/Documents/C++/helloWorld'
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
> ```

How to fix it and configure NetBeans (with C++ package) correctly?

Comment: Please post the code/errors directly, instead of links. Links will die over time, and then the question becomes useless for others.

Comment: @jonsca Yes, I did new project (File -> New Project... -> C/C++ Application).

@Space_C0wb0y Okey, I will fix it. Give me a minute... =]

Comment: I got the same problem, I add msys to path, I check the folders and I got this error:

/usr/bin/[: missing `]'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess you didn't add msys to your `PATH` variable. See [this entry in the Netbeans forum](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic38061.html), as the error reported there is essentially the same as the one you pasted in your question. So, the error message you received does not complain about make, it complains that it can't find `mkdir`, which is supposed to be in a directory in your msys directory. Adding `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\` to your windows `PATH` variable will probably be sufficient to fix this.

Comment: This fix that problem. Thanks. Anyway, I can't run *.exe file even from my machine! And it is 39 kB big! I will better stick to Java! =]

Comment: @daGrevis: You can't run the resulting exe file? Did you try to run it from the command line?

Comment: "The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.ddl is missing from your computer. Try reintalling the program to fix this problem."

Comment: You can find a "fix" (linking statically) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984612/program-cant-find-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll . Well, that's not the best solution, but will be sufficient for smaller examples. Apart from that, maybe the msys shell could be used to run the exe?

Comment: After doing this, restarting Netbeans solved the issue.

Comment: In my case it was that I did not have the right location of `make.exe` in the Netbeans settings. I simply downloaded `make` from Cygwin and pointed it to the right location and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

mkdir in Cygwin may be a separate .exe instead of a function of bash. So you may be just missing it for some reason.

Comment: But it is MinGW. This answer didn't help me. Can't accept it! =[

Answer (score 0):

"Resolve Missing Native Build Tools" Netbeans Make command problem. Go to -Tools -Options -C/C++ Write to Make Command: C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe

Answer (score -2):

Solution
Copy `mingw32-make.exe` from `MinGW\bin\` to `msys` folder, replacing `make.exe`

not sure why this is necessary but, hey, it worked.