# JNI: Library is Found on Path, but Method is not (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, codeblocks, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to use JNI and getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.  Unlike the other million questions asked about this, I have the lib on my path, and have even seen the exception change when I remove it.  I'm sure that something is wrong with the dll I have created, but I'm not sure what.

Here is my java class code:

```
package com;

public class Tune {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("lala");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tune j = new Tune();
        System.out.println("2+6="+j.add(2, 6));
    }
    native public int add(int x,int y);
}
```

Here is the abridged portion of my javah produced header file:

```
/*
 * Class:     com_Tune
 * Method:    add
 * Signature: (II)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_Tune_add
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);
```

Here is my c++ code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <com_Tune.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_Tune_add
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jint x, jint y) {
    return x+y;
  }
```

Here is the runtime exception I get from eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.Tune.add(II)I
    at com.Tune.add(Native Method)
    at com.Tune.main(Tune.java:9)
```

I read that the above exception means it DID find the library "lala", but that the method "add" is still not defined.  The only things I see different between my project and the tutorial are:

- Mine uses a package, instead of the default package (shouldn't tutorials really do this?!?! come on let's get professional)

  - Mine has a return value.
  - I moved my dll after it was created (I don't think this will break it since my path is configured.)

How is this possible?

## Other Info:

OS: Windows 7
JDK: 1.6.0_31 (for x86, 32 bit jvm)
C++ IDE: Code::Blocks (the dll was compiled automatically by the Code::Blocks IDE)
C++ compiler: MinGW32-g++ (the GNU C++ compiler)

I have jni.h and com_Tune.h in C:\_\include
I have lala.dll in C:\_\lib

Environment Variables:
PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Apps;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_INSTALL%\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:_\path;C:\_\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin;C:\_\include

Comment: The code seems correct. Could you check DLL export table (i.e. with Dependency Walker) and make sure that your function is present in exports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing... Is your dll depends on another dll that is not on the path? MinGW modules usually depend on specific C runtime library.

Comment: ok, I'm trying your advice to use Dependency walker.  I'm unfortunately new to C++, and this is the first I heard of dependency walker.  Not sure how to use it to detect missing dependencies.  I opened "lala.dll" with it, and selected the root node in the tree.  The "Pi" table is empty.  The "E" table has one entry for a function.  Function: Java_com_Tune_add@16.  Ordinal: 1(0x0 0 0 1).  Hint:  0(0x0 0 0 0).  Entry Point: 0x0 0 0 0 1 2 5 4.  Can you please tell me what I should be looking for?

Comment: Also, the "E" column has a block with the letter "C" in it, not "C++". Could that be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that is it. Your function is exported. The "C" mark is normal, "C++" marks methods of C++ classes, as i know. Look at direct children of root node. That is imported libraries. What is there exactly? For your "just-simple-method-library" case there must be few entries. I.e. in my test dll (also with one simple method) there are only two libraries.

Comment: immediate children: KERNEL32.DLL, MSVCRT.DLL, LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL.  The first two have a lot of their own child nodes.  I clicked on each node in the tree, never saw a red block under PI or E.

Comment: Last step to make my assumption wrong :) Copy LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.DLL to directory with your dll. And add to static init block `System.loadLibrary("LIBGCC_S_DW2-1");` before loading your lib.

Comment: that did not fix it, should I try searching on the other libs and seeing if they are on my PATH?

Comment: I decided to rebuild the project with Visual Studio.  Guess what, it works!  So obviously the problem is somehow produced by the MinGW32 compiler.

Comment: To make things extra weird, I decided to use dependency walker on the working dll.  To my surprise, it says that it's missing two libraries: GPSVC.DLL, and IESHIMS.DLL.  Despite that, it's functional?!?!  The more I work with c++, the less sense it makes.  I give up.

Comment: Dependency walker just say that some libraries are not accessible in usual dll loading manner. But they still may be loadable by target application. Also look at solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984612/program-cant-find-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll). Recommendation is to do static linkage, so result dll will contain all necessary code.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the name compiler has generated: `Java_com_Tune_add@16`

Use either of two

`gcc -Wl,-kill-at`

Or

`gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias`

This will ensure generation of Java_com_Tune_add

And then your method call will be successful.

Comment: For the further note, this answer is the correct answer and this fixes my problem. I think this is the answer which should be accepted. Instead others who dig to this thread later will mislead.

Answer (score 2):

One possible source of the problem might be that you compiled the code using a C++ compiler, which uses a different [calling convention] than plain C. If thats the case then the solution would be to wrap the code for the method in a `extern "C"` block like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_Tune_add
...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but that unfortunately did not fix it.

Comment: I think msknapp have omitted preprocessor directives in his question. `javah`, the tool that generates headers for JNI, adds necessary stuff automatically.

Comment: Like I said in the question, the javah output was abridged to keep the question short.  I did not change anything that was output by javah.  If you really want to see all of it, here you go:  /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_Tune */

#ifndef _Included_com_Tune
#define _Included_com_Tune
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_Tune
 * Method:    add
 * Signature: (II)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_Tune_add
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif

Comment: @Mersenne: You're right, that `extern` declaration is only needed in the header, which is generated. I looked at the wrong part of my own sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the flag -Wl,-kill-at worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following example for Windows:
(remember that the Java class name must be the same that corresponding file name)

Step 1. Create the following Java file (P.java):

```
class P
{
  static
  {
    // "P" is the name of DLL without ".dll"
    System.loadLibrary ("P");
  }

  public static native void f(int i);

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    f(1);
  }
}
```

Step 2. javac P.java

Step 3. javah P

Then, "javah" generates the header file "P.h"

Step 4. Create the file "P.def" including the following two lines (this file defines the exported symbols, in this case the name of C function):

```
EXPORTS
Java_P_f
```

Step 5. Create your C file (P.c):

```
#include "P.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_P_f(JNIEnv *env, jclass c, jint i)
{
  printf("%i\n",i);
}
```

Step 6. Within Visual Studio command promt, define the following variables:

set JAVA_HOME= the path of JDK

set include=%include%;%JAVA_HOME%\include;%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32

Step 7. Generate DLL:

cl /LD P.c P.def

Step 8. Run the Java program:

java P

(Note: P.dll and P.class are located in the same directory)