# codeblocks 12.11 opencv imshow not working

Tags: opencv, codeblocks

i write codes like this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("lena.jpg");
    if(!image.data)
    {
        cout << "error" <<endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("window");
    imshow("window",image);
    waitKey(27);
    return 0;
}
```

and in codeblocks 12.11 :

it cannot show the image,and the windows says

```
     XX.exe has stopped working
        windows is checking for a solution to the problem...
```

and in qtcreator 2.4.1

the result is ok.

and i tried cvImageShow both ok

a broblem of codeblocks 12.11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problems.

I changed the gcc version in codeblocks 12.11

I download gcc 4.6.1 to the /Program Files/codeblocks/MinGW

then the opencv program till not working because of missing libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

google the libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll and put it into  /Program Files/codeblocks/MinGW/bin

success!

and maybe this link:[OpenCV program cannot run because of missing "libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll" in Code::Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700935/opencv-program-cannot-run-because-of-missing-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-in-codeblock)
    may help this kind of problem.