# libopencv_core310.dll missing error message

Tags: opencv, codeblocks

When I try to compile opencv program with codeblocks this error appears
[dll error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBjmt.png) But I have the file in the directory. I've followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb9n8gQ0RwA&list=PLkPmSWtWNIyT8EpMEqi4wSKOJRegyAYJk&index=1).
 So after this I followed another tutorial(codeblocks opencv link without any doubt (code blocks10.05 mingw opencv 2.4.3)) which showing the solution of this problem.They used codeblocks 10.
Searching for solution, there is no specific one. Then I followed this 
Again I tried this( docs.opencv.org). Why is this problem generating? Is this a version problem of opencv or codeblocks? Do I have to configure mingw again as I'm using 64 bit windows and codeblocks 13.12 .

Comment: I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700935/opencv-program-cannot-run-because-of-missing-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-in-codeblock?rq=1 but it is not helping

Comment: Are you sure that your libopencv_core310.dll is in your current directory?

Comment: Yes, it is in my current directory

Comment: I recommend you to double check the current directory since sometimes it's different from the folder which .exe is in. Then check the dll is correct, there are 64/32 bit versions and static/debug versions. Dependency Walker http://www.dependencywalker.com/ will help you.