# libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing making OpenCV and Qt 5 program is unable to start

Tags: opencv, qt5, dll

My project needs opencv library 2.3 and I'm using Qt 5.0.1. However, after building, the program won't start. I tried the Dependency Walker and added all Qt's dlls from C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin **except libgcc_s_dw2-2.dll**, which I couldn't find in my computer.  The Dependency Walker says that libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is needed by some opencv dlls such as libopencv_core230.dll. I tried the dll provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9334351/957121), but got an error about the program couldn't locate the input entrance __gxx_personality_v0 on libopencv_imgproc230.dll. Any advices? :)

I've added the statement

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lpthread
```

into .pro file, not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, get it work.

The statement above is wrong since -lpthread is 'no use'.
I changed it to this one:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

It seems that -lpthread should be used with -static next to it, ie. -static -lpthread. However, this will cause another problem that the compiler can't find opencv libs. So I just remove them and add libpthread-1.dll to the .exe folder.

Many thanks to [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703059/957121)

Comment: Update: it only works under Release mode. In debug mode, dlls is still needed.

Answer (score 0):

If it don't work, try using .lib from "vc9" directory.