# c++ program failed to run on another pc with libgcc error

Tags: c++, build, codeblocks, libgcc

I wrote some simple code in C++, and I built it and ran it on my laptop, and everything as working. When I tried to run the .exe file on my brother's laptop, it gave me this error `The program can't start because libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.` Am I missing something that I should have added or something?

Note: I don't know if it matters or not, but I'm using Code::Blocks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matters because you used Code::Blocks. If you don't know about it, you most probably used Code::Blocks with [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). Install it on that machine followed by a reboot may fix it.

C++ programs need to have a *runtime library* -- you can think of it as needing .NET Framework to run C# or JRE to run Java programs. Visual C++ uses `msvcrt` (known as Visual C++ Runtime). Many installations of Windows seem to come with `msvcrt` by default which may explain why people using MSVC is less likely to run into issues like this.

If you [statically link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) the CRT (C Run Time) you can lift the requirements of the clients having to have the DLL files installed, at the expense of having a larger `.exe` file.

A relevant SO answer: [The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702732/the-program-cant-start-because-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-is-missing)

Answer (score 2):

You can place that DLL in the same folder as the .exe on your release and it should work