# Trouble with OpenCv in code blocks

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I have followed the official guide for setting up OpenCv in codeblocks.I did everything as in the guide.I succeded to compile one code of the samples of opencv but when I run I have an error that some .dll is missing.More precisely this is the error:The application can't start because libopencv_core242.dll is missing from your computer..Try reinstaling the application...The awkward thing is that this static library is present in the bin folder under build->x64->mingw->bin..
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to copy the dll into the folder containing the executable.

For a "cleaner" solution, it has been answered here (with libgcc) : [The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702732/the-program-cant-start-because-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-is-missing)

Basically, either you copy the dll containing folder into the PATH ENV, or you can try to link with the statically.

Comment: I did so, and now I get this:The application was unable to start correctly( 0xc000007b ).

Comment: it may be due to an 32/64 bit issue : [0xc000007b Error Solution](http://msoos.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/0xc000007b-error-solution/)

Comment: It doesn't seem to solve the problem for me..I have a 64bit win7 if it matters.