# MinGW compiled programs crash on 64 bit Windows

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mingw

I have 32bit MinGW and 64 bit Eclipse CDT installed on 64 bit Windows 7 with an Intel `Core i7-3612QM`. When I compile and run `hello world`, the string prints, but the program gets a `SIGILL` afterward.

Source:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
hello.exe [C/C++ Application]   
    hello.exe [5532]    
        Thread [1] 0 (Suspended : Signal : SIGILL:Illegal instruction)  
            libstdc++-6!_ZSt4cout() at 0x6fccc3c0   
            libstdc++-6!_ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E() at 0x6fc8908c    
            _fu0___ZSt4cout() at hello.cpp:5 0x4013be   
    gdb
```

Adding `cin` causes a segfault:

Source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;
    cout << "Please type your name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Verbose compiler output:

```
C:\Users\Sean\temp>g++ -v main.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,obj
c,obj-c++ --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --enable-shared --enable-libgo
mp --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-r
untime-libs --build=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.2 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\min
gw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/ main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -mtune=i386
-march=i386 -auxbase main -version -o C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSVBzeY.
s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.6.2 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.6.2, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 2.4.1,
MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../.
./mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/inclu
de/c++"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/inclu
de/c++/mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/inclu
de/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/inclu
de"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/inclu
de-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../
../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/mingw32
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/backward
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.6.2 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.6.2, GMP version 5.0.1, MPFR version 2.4.1,
MPC version 0.8.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: f7eb4168c2cf10318cc29da8d23b7f3c
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -o C:\User
s\Sean\AppData\Local\Temp\ccb0vTGl.o C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSVBzeY.s

COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec
/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/
mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/
gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../;/mingw/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=i386' '-march=i386'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/collect2.exe -Bdynamic -u ___register
_frame_info -u ___deregister_frame_info c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/..
/../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/crtbegin.o -Lc:/mingw/bin/..
/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw
32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../.
. -L/mingw/lib C:\Users\Sean\AppData\Local\Temp\ccb0vTGl.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -l
gcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel
32 -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc
/mingw32/4.6.2/crtend.o
```

Stacktrace:

```
hello.exe [C/C++ Application]   
    hello.exe [9092]    
        Thread [1] 0 (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)  
            libstdc++-6!_ZNSs12_Alloc_hiderC1EPcRKSaIcE() at 0x6fc89542 
            libstdc++-6!_ZNSsC1Ev() at 0x6fc8c38b   
            main() at hello.cpp:7 0x4013a7  
    gdb
```

The problems also occur using 32 bit `code::blocks` or when compiled manually from the command line.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can we see what the command(s) to  compile/link are and what `gcc -v` says? Also, does it behave the same if you compile/link/run from the command line instead of from within Eclipse?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Added `g++ -v` compiler output; exes still have the same problems.

Comment: Where did you get the MinGW installation? I wonder if something is 'off' with the libstdc++.dll.  Maybe a reinstall of MinGW might be in order.  I've had great experience with the TDM distributions (http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) or nuwen's MinGW (http://nuwen.net/mingw.html)

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm using a fresh install MinGW and MSYS from http://www.mingw.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I tried to run the EXE on another computer that didn't have MinGW intalled, it complained:

> The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from you
>   computer.  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Googling that error led me to the SO question [The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702732/the-program-cant-start-because-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-is-missing)

From the answer:

> The `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` should be in the compiler's bin directory.
>   You can add this directory to your PATH environment variable for
>   runtime linking, or you can avoid the problem by adding
>   "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" to your compiler flags.

So I added the flags, and the resulting program ran normally on both systems. I'm not sure why these flags were required for it to work properly on my dev system, because the MinGW bin directory is in the PATH. Can anyone provide an explinantion? Should I create a seperate question?