# Debug build of hello world crashes, depending on optimization level

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, windows-8.1

This simple hello world programm (taken from eclipse) crashes on exiting when I do a debug build:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

I build it with:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
g++ -o test.exe main.o
```

When I run test.exe the console opens (with the message) but I also get a crash-message (test.exe has stopped working) with the error code 0xc0000005 (access violation). Now if I compile the same file with -O1 instead of -O0, the resulting executable runs without problems. I am running Windows 8.1 (64 bit), the executable is 32 bit, and I am using mingw with g++ being version 4.8.1.

Does someone know what might cause this problem?

Comment: Since this is such a short program it may be useful to look at the assembly.

Comment: in terms of ur mingw, is it 64-bit or 32 bit?

Comment: The mingw installation is 32 bit.

Comment: Use `g++ -O0 -g3 -S main.cpp` to get the assembly, it will be in a file called main.s, and post it here.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/uPH0taah) is the version without g3 (since that adds over 6000 lines of debug stuff). I found out that the crash has something to do with the endl (see [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2219/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a problem on a such a simple code, then very likely it is a bug in this version of mingw with this set of compiler keys. It can be useful to write about this behavior in mingw support.

Comment: You might be right, I've searched in their bugtracker and found [this bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2219/) which seems similar, maybe identical. I tried removing the std::endl out of my code and it ran just fine even with -O0 so there seems to be something wrong with that.

Comment: As I was able to narrow my search I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621639/stdendl-crashes-windows-8-compiled-using-mingw) question, and the workaround seems to be statically linking the std library.