# typeinfo name() and endl don't work together in Windows and mingw

Tags: c++, windows-8, mingw, typeid, ubuntu-13.10

When I run this simple code in Ubuntu (Ubuntu 13.10, 64 bits, g++ 4.8.1) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    const type_info &ti_trait = typeid(char_traits<char>::char_type);

    cout << "Traits character type name : " <<
        ti_trait.name() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

everything is OK, but in Windows (Windows 8 64 bits, mingw, g++ 4.8.1), I got "The program has stopped working" (the compilation works fine and -Wall produces no warning).

The same code compiled and executed in Visual Studio works correctly.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you determined that it's the line with the call to `name` on it that causes it to fail?

Comment: @sftrabbit Yes, but I don't understand why...

Comment: Oddly, the problem comes from endl. If I remove it, the program works correctly!?

Comment: 64 bit Windows? [Have you had a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14368482/150634)?

Comment: This solved the problem! I have to compile with "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++". Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to compile with `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` ([see here for an explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368482/mingw-compiled-programs-crash-on-64-bit-windows)). Thanks to @sftrabbit.