# std::endl results in crash

Tags: c++, crash, stdout, std, mingw32

During the development of a simple example (I haven't programmed C++ for some time) I encountered a weird behaviour. Following hello world program crashes under Windows (Mingw):

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {

    for (int idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++) {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I remove `std::endl` the program does not crash though.

I use following commands to compile and execute the example, with Mingw32 (g++ 4.8.1) on a 64bit system and OS:

```
g++ example.cpp -o example.exe
example.exe
```

The error message is:

> example.exe does not work any longer...

Is this a known issue or an obvious mistake of mine?

Comment: The very meaningful report from Windows "example.exe does not work any longer..."

Comment: What version of mingw are you using? Are you using 32bit or 64bit system and compiler? Looks like a library version clash

Comment: I am using Mingw32 (with g++ 4.8.1) on a 64bit system and OS. But a 32bit application should usually not be a problem on a 64bit system. I could of course test Mingw-w64...

Comment: Please do test it. And yes, I agree, 32bit apps should work with no problems, I suspect some misconfiguration in your build system, however I don't know much about Windows.

Comment: Try to catch an exception - maybe one is thrown?

Comment: @Spook I am wondering, how he would display it :)

Comment: @Erbureth `OutputDebugString`, for instance.

Comment: @Spook: If I use try-catch I get another error showing that "__gxx_personality_v0" has not been found. Maybe it is indeed a misconfiguration of the whole build system.

Comment: You could have sent a bug report, if we'd believe in such a crash in normal environment.

Comment: Wild guess, maybe it's a privileges related problem, e.g. run the console as administrator?

Comment: @SChepurin: Where? You mean for Mingw?

Comment: @hauron: Does not work either.

Comment: @user3575404 - relatively rare visitors here run g++ under Windows (in mingw), and sure they could not reproduce this crazy behavior.

Comment: what if you try 

`g++ -m32 example.cpp -o example.exe`

Comment: Probably the same issue as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368482/mingw-compiled-programs-crash-on-64-bit-windows. Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621639/stdendl-crashes-windows-8-compiled-using-mingw.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using a consistent implementation of headers/compiler and shared library for the standard C++ library?

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: It still crashes.

Comment: @ Dietmar Kühl: No. How?

Comment: @user3575404 What IDE are you using ? or are you just compiling the code via Dos ?

Comment: I would argue that when this crashes, your installation is somehow corrupted and you might consider reinstalling everything.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Funny thing is: I just installed it.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: Currently just via dos.

Comment: I see now that the problem does not occur with the cygwin implementation. Guess it is some kind of a misconfiguration or bug with mingw then. I will try and report this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

<< endl is a manipulation essentially a function. your output cant be flushed which is causing problems.