# How to configure NetBeans to statically link MinGW C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, netbeans, mingw

I have built an executable file (.exe), but when I run it, a window pops up which says

> The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Can I configure Netbeans to include that file into the .exe file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

In Netbeans, right-click on the project node in the Projects window, then click **Properties**. Click the **Build** > **Linker** node. Under the **Compilation Line** category, there is a field named **Additional options**. Now enter the following line:

```
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

Click **OK**. Now it works.

*Notice that your file is much larger than if it were compiled without the library. If you are not (yet) planning to distribute the executable, then maybe it's a better option to set the PATH environment variable. See [The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702732/the-program-cant-start-because-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-is-missing) for more details.*