# "Can't load OpenGL extension [glBindBuffer] in function IntGetProcAddress" exception of OpenCV in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, exception, opengl, opencv

I downloaded OpenCV 2.4.6 from the opencv website. To avoid the problem I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565182/libgcc-s-sjlj-1-dll-is-missing-in-qt-5-1), I decided to compile the OpenCV library. After CMake and Mingw32-make, the compile succeeded. However, a simple test program crashes when tring to show a jpeg image. Here is my .pro and main.cpp file:

.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

#INCLUDEPATH += D:/opencv2.4.6/build/include
INCLUDEPATH += D:/opencv2.4.6/release/install/include
LIBS += -LD:/opencv2.4.6/release/install/bin \
    -lopencv_core246 \
    -lopencv_highgui246 \
    -lopencv_imgproc246 \
    -lopencv_features2d246 \
    -lopencv_calib3d246
```

main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    Mat input = imread("Z:/1.jpg");
    cv::imshow("1.jpg",input);
}
```

Here is the problem:

```
OpenCV Error: OpenGL API call (Can't load OpenGL extension [glBindBuffer]) in In
tGetProcAddress, file ..\..\..\modules\core\src\gl_core_3_1.cpp, line 141
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  ..\..\..\modules\core\src\gl_core_3_1.cpp:141: error: (-219) Can't lo
ad OpenGL extension [glBindBuffer] in function IntGetProcAddress


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I've never encountered such problem before. It's kind of weird. What should I do to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After trying to compile OpenCV, it seems that the WITH_OPENGL should be unchecked. Now the program runs normally.