# how can build options be changed in code::blocks?

Tags: c++, build, codeblocks

I recently started using code::blocks, so I'm a newb here.
I am writing a game, in SDL with C++ and all of the code I am writing depends on the build options similar to this: `g++ -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -lSDL -lSDL_image`

Code::Blocks seems to work fine when I select to start a NEW SDL project, and convert my programs to project files. However, I have many source files, and I dont want to convert them all to project files, I would rather just change the build options for code blocks.

I am using version svn 10528, on Linux if that helps. I have formerly been using geany, which was very simple to change, and set build options in.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "convert your programs to project files".
You don't do any "converting" to add a source file to a C::B project.
You just add existing or new source files to a project, and a project can contain as many source files as you like. To set build options for <your_project>, right-click <your_project> in the workspace view and select **Build options**. It's really very obvious if you've already built programs with GCC and I'm sure you can work it out, perhaps with the aid of [the documentation](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/User_documentation)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found it, In Code::Blocks, go to Project> Build options 
a window appears. it lists build options.
right click on that and add new. from there you can give it a name, add compiler options, and add linker options.

[image]

save it and youre done.

I saw some errors in the IDE when trying to use this, and found if you click continue it works fine. if you click cancel, the IDE crashes.