# g++ cannot link stdc++ statically (windows)

Tags: c++, windows, g++

I've been doing a simple c++ program with use of curlpp library. I can build and compile everything just right and I can run it if having MinGW in my PATH. When I delete it and copy all curlpp dlls in the directory, it says (of course):

```
The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

I believe that the problem is that std libraries are not linked statically, but I tried all possibilities and it seems as they are not linked. I type:

```
g++ -o myApp.exe main.cpp -std=gnu++11 -L(curl,curlpp,opensll) -I(all includes) -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++  -Wl,-Bdynamic -lcurlpp -lcurl -Wl,--as-needed
```

with no errors, then I run it and I get error from above. Of course, if I have MinGW in my PATH, then everything works.

I tried to change the order of options in the command without any luck. Putting `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` as advised elsewhere is not working. 
Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The program can't start because libgcc\_s\_dw2-1.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702732/the-program-cant-start-because-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-is-missing)

Comment: @VTT: Been there and as you can see from my code,  -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++ didn't work.

Comment: You also need to make sure that all the dynamic libraries you are trying to use won't link them dynamically. You can use something like dependency walker to inspect where `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` demand is coming from.