# C++ Program Won't Run From Windows Console

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, mingw

I'm learning C++ and I have completed a basic Hello World program. The program runs fine in my IDE, but I am unable to run it from my Windows console.

I am using the MinGW compiler.

I have already added it to my path.

I am using Windows 10.

I am using the Eclipse IDE.

When I try to run my program, I get the error that

```
The code execution cannot proceed because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the 
program may fix this problem.
```

I double checked the bin folder in MinGW and it does have the libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll file. And, as I said, MinGW is set to my path.

I know that there is a question like this already but those solutions did not help me. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: my compiler bin directory has been added to my path.

Comment: Check the path from the console, type the command `path` and check that the folder containing the dll is listed.

Comment: Get rid of mingw, eclipse and, generally, all *nix developer tools ported to Windows are outdated, they will only cause uneccessary trouble and should be avoided unless there is a  reason to use them (say, developing a cross platform app).

Comment: This error indicates missing redistributable packages.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis What's so bad about it? The latest versions of common tools are available (latest GCC, Clang, `make`, and what not).

Comment: You certainly have picked a difficult path. MSVC 2019 with a Desktop C++ workload configuration would've worked out of the box.. having said that,  have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702732/the-program-cant-start-because-libgcc-s-dw2-1-dll-is-missing).

Comment: @rustyx To be fair, MinGW requires minimal configuration. Adding a compiler directory to `PATH` is not hard.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I am following a C++ tutorial that uses those tools so I'd rather stick with them.

Comment: Tutorials are very bad for learning C++. You need proper books and a good teacher.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat a debugger, intellisense, and most important, the updated SDK. Direct2D, ribbon,sensors, animation editor etc. It's only useful for the raw beginner and still, VS 2019 is free.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis The Windows SDK (and related tools) is a valid point. We do have decent IDEs though, with intellisense-like features and visual debugging support. (But maybe not as polished as VS.) So, "for the raw beginner" and for those who don't need the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

> I double checked the bin folder in MinGW and it does have the libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll file.

Add your compiler `bin` directory to `PATH`.

**OR** copy this `.dll` to the directory where your `.exe` is. You'll have to do the same thing for `libstdc++….dll` and probably also `libwinpthreads….dll`.

Note that if you decide to distribute your `.exe` to other people, you'll have to distribute those `.dll`s with it. In general, you can use `ntldd` or a similar tool to figure out which `.dll`s your program depends on.

Comment: Hi @HolyBlackCat, I have my compiler's ```bin``` to ```PATH``` already but am still having this problem.

Interestingly, though, I do not see ```libwinpthreads... .dll``` in my compiler's bin directory. Could this be what's causing the problem?

Comment: @Andrew If there's no `libwinpthreads`, then you don't need it; the specific dlls that your programs use by default depend on the MinGW distribution. There's a possibility that there's some stray incompatible `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` either in `C:\Windows`/`C:\Windows\System32` (in that case delete it, it shouldn't be there), or in one of the directories in the `PATH` (in that case remove the offending dir from `PATH`). Or you can copy the dlls instead, as I said.